# A co-isosimple module is co-cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, module-isomorphism

I have tried to prove the statement that if an R-module is co-isosimple, then it is co-cyclic. In the paper that this stated, this is mentioned as since a co-isosimple module is artinian and uniserial, so is co-cyclic, but this is not clear for me. I need some hints for the proof. 
If a non-zero module $M$ is isomorphic to all its non-zero quotients,then it is called $\textbf{co-isosimple}$. 
A module $M$ is called $\textbf{co-cyclic}$ if there is a simple module that is essential in M.

To improve my question: I know that every Artinian module has a simple submodule and every submodule of a uniserial module is essential. Therefore if a module is both Artinian and uniserial, then it has a simple essential submodule, that is, it is co-cyclic. Furthermore, I've just realized that a co-isosimple module has uniserial dimension 1 so is a co-isosimple module is uniserial. However, I haven't proved that part, a co-isosimple module is Artinian, so I still need some hints for this one.

Comment: Thanks for improving this question.

Comment: How do you know your module has uniserial dimension in the first place?

Comment: In one of the papers, written by A. Facchini and Z. Nazemian, that I've read for my thesis, there is the definition of uniserial dimension like, let A be the class of all R-modules. $A_0$ has only the zero module and $A_1$ be the class of all uniserial R-modules. Then the definition goes like, for $A_i$, where i>1, for submodules N of M, if M/N is not isomorphic to M, then M/N is in the union of $A_0$, $A_1$, ..., $A_k$, where k<i. Then, if a module is behind for some $A_i$, it has uniserial dimension i. In my question since M is co-isosimple, then for all N of M, M/N is isomorphic to M.